# Looking for a library to get point address in OSMDroid for Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, osmdroid

How can I get an address of the point (or a point by the address) in OSMDroid library? Should I use another libraries or Geopackages? Where can I get it?

I've already tried to use MapListener but it returns only coordinates.

Comment: You are looking for _Geocoding_ and _Reverse Geocoding_ and [OSMBonusPack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) has those features, apparently. Some more info on the topic: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925204/simple-example-reverse-geocoding-osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925204/simple-example-reverse-geocoding-osmdroid)